# File link in amazon aws s3 bucket using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-net

I have some images stored on AWS S3 bucket. I am using ASP.NET SDK. Now I can upload/download/delete files through the SDK. But what I want is to get a link to the image files so that if I want to display an image, I can show its thumbnail on my website. I am unable to find anything in ASP.NET. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Refer to this link
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingNetSDK.html

Comment: Kindly read my question again. I know how to download/upload/delete files. I am interested in generating a link for every file.

Comment: You can work it out for yourself given the bucket and the file name you specify in the upload request.
e.g. if your bucket is mybucket and your file is named myfilename:
https://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com/myfilename



The s3 bit will be different depending on which region your bucket is in. For example, I use the south-east asia region so my urls are like:

https://mybucket.s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/myfilename